# Building an application to transform CSV files

Tags: php, mysql, sql, excel, csv

I have a rough and complete working CSV transformer. The way my current system works is it imports the CSV file into an SQL database table with static column names, and exports only specific (needed) columns. This system works great but is only specific to one type of CSV file (because the column names are pre-defined.) I'm wondering how I can make this universal. Instead of having it insert column1, column2, column3. I want to insert Spreadsheet Column1, Spreadsheet Column2, Spreadsheet Column3, etc. How would I go about pulling the column names from the CSV file, and creating a new table in the database with the column names being those from the first row of the CSV file.

The current system:

- Client uploads CSV file.
- A table is created with predefined column names (column 1, column 2, column 3)
- Using LOAD DATA INFILE -> PHP scripts will insert the information from the CSV file into the recently created table.
- The next query that is ran is simply something along the lines of taking only specific columns out of the table and exporting it to a final CSV file.

The system that would be ideal:

- Client uploads CSV file.
- PHP scripts read the CSV file and takes only the first row (column names), after taking these column names, it'll create a new table based on the column names.
- PHP scripts now use LOAD DATA INFILE.
- The rest is the same as current system.

Current code:

import.php

```
include("/inc/database.php");
include("/inc/functions.php"); 
include("/inc/data.php"); 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$string = random_string(7);
$new_file_name = 'report_'. $string .'.csv';
$themove = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], 'C:/xampp/htdocs/uploads/'.$new_file_name);
        mysql_query("CREATE TABLE report_". $string ."(". $colNames .")") or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '/xampp/htdocs/uploads/report_". $string .".csv'
INTO TABLE report_". $string ."
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(". $insertColNames .")";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    header('Location: download.php?dlname='.$string.'');
}
```

data.php (shortened most of this. In reality there are about 200 columns going in, twenty-thirty coming out)

```
<?php
$colNames = "Web_Site_Member_ID text, 
Master_Member_ID text, 
API_GUID text, 
Constituent_ID text";
$insertColNames = "Web_Site_Member_ID,
Master_Member_ID,
API_GUID,
Constituent_ID";
$exportNames = "Web_Site_Member_ID, Date_Membership_Expires, Membership, Member_Type_Code";
?>
```

functions.php just includes the block of code for generating a random string/file name.

Comment: I think you should try to code what you're asking for and ask us a more precise question when you'll encounter a precise problem.

Comment: **Post your current code.**

Comment: Ahh, CSV. Did you use `fgetcsv` ?

Comment: Anthony, thanks for posting your code but I still do not see you attempting to use the fgetcsv function in your example. We cannot help you if we can't see what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For CSV file reading please look at the [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function. You should easily be able to extract a row of data and access each individual field in the resulting array for your column header definitions.

Comment: I have tried messing around with fgetcsv() with no avail. I'll try to mess around with it some more. Instead of $data[0] being the first row, cell 1. and $data[1] being the first row, cell 2. It would read the information downwards.

Comment: If you post the code you have perhaps we can better help point out what you're doing wrong.